# Alternative image when file doesn't exists

Tags: php

So, I use images from my server and images from other sites. Now I have a problem, sometimes images doesn't exists. How can I show alternative image for it? Currently I've been using `getimagesize();`but it is too slow. Any idea what to use? It must be fast and reliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `curl` also in this case:

```
function check_image($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); // do not get the body
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    return (curl_exec($ch) !== false);
}

$image = check_image('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.png?v=3c6263c3453b');
var_dump($image);
$image = check_image('http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/testing.png');
var_dump($image);
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using javascript

Handle the onError event for the image to reassign its source using JavaScript:

```
function imgError(image) {
   image.onerror = "";
   image.src = "/images/noimage.gif";
  return true;}

<img src="image.jpg" onError="imgError(this);" />
```

Answer (score 1):

For local files use:

```
if(file_exists($filename)) 
{
   ... show image ... 
} 
else 
{ 
   ... show this-image-is-missing-image ... 
}
```

(`$filename` is of courser the file name for your image).

For remote files, you will need something like this:

```
function get_curl_filetime($remote_name)
{
    $ch = curl_init($remote_name);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILETIME, TRUE);

    $filetime = -1;
    if (curl_exec($ch) !== false)
    {
        $filetime = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_FILETIME);
    }

    curl_close($ch);
    return $filetime;
}
```

(It's probably not necessary to actually get the tiletime, just some access - this comes from a system I use for caching/copying files, so I need to know the time to know if I need to update)

Comment: I know this works with local files, but will it work if I use files from another servers?

Comment: Sorry, missed that part of the question. It can be done, but you basically have to request the (status of) the image of the other server. Hang on.